# Fastest way to remove an item from each sublist with max length in a list of lists

Tags: performance, python-2.7, list

Given a list of lists:

```
l = [[],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[3,1,4,2,0],[],[2]]
```

I remove item `2` from each sublist by:

```
l = [[j for j in i if j !=2] for i in l]
```

Is there any faster way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interesting question!

i tried 3 different versions and (for your list - don't know the general or average case) got a *tiny*(!) speedup by checking if `2` was in the sublist first. my attempts are not exhaustive:

```
from timeit import timeit
n_timeit = 1000


l = [[],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[3,1,4,2,0],[],[2]]


def f1(l):
    return [[j for j in i if j != 2] for i in l]


def f2(l):
    return [sublist if 2 not in sublist
            else list(filter(lambda x: x != 2, sublist)) for sublist in l]


def f3(l):
    return [sublist if 2 not in sublist
            else [item for item in sublist if item != 2] for sublist in l]


t1 = timeit(setup='from __main__ import f1, l',
            stmt='f1(l)',
            number=n_timeit)
t2 = timeit(setup='from __main__ import f2, l',
            stmt='f2(l)',
            number=n_timeit)
t3 = timeit(setup='from __main__ import f3, l',
            stmt='f3(l)',
            number=n_timeit)

print(t1)  # 0.00488
print(t2)  # 0.00943
print(t3)  # 0.00466
```

oh, tested on python3; don't know how any of this performs on python2.

note the difference between your approach and mine: in yours you create new lists in any case; in mine you get a reference to the lists that do not contain 2 instead of a fresh list.